# mongodb $slice elements out of deep nested array

Tags: mongodb

I have a deep nested array like this:

```
_id: userId,
posts: [
   {
      _id: postId,
      comments: [{...},{...}]
   }
]
```

I have 2 Inputs:

`userId`
`postId`

Now i want to slice the last 5 elements out of the comments array with `$slice: [-5, 5]` but i dont exactly know how to select such a deep nested array correctly.

My attempt was to slice it out like this, but it failed:

```
  let result = await Post.aggregate([
    {
      $match: {
        _id: userId,
        "posts._id": postId
      }
    },
    {
      "posts.$.comments": {
        $slice: [-5, 5]
      }
    },
    {
      $project: {
        posts: 1
      }
    }
  ]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use [`$map`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/) expression and return a new sliced `comments` array and set it back again to `posts` array:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      _id: userId,
      "posts._id": postId
    }
  },
  {
    "$addFields": {
      "posts": {
        "$map": {
          "input": "$posts", "as": "p",
          "in": {
            "_id": "$$p._id",
            "comments": { "$slice": [ "$$p.comments", -5, 5 ] }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      posts: {
        $filter: {
          input: "$posts", as: "posts",
          cond: { $eq: [ "$$posts._id", postId ] }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

I have not tested the slicing part. Please check the [`$slice`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/slice/) docs once to match it with your requirement.

Comment: it works almost. the problem i face now is that it returns all posts instead of just 1

Comment: maybe you can help me here out. i slice more and more comments from an array out. but if i reach the end lets say my array is 50 long, and i try to slice out for example `$slice: [-70, 5]` it still slices me 5 elements out so i load over and over the same comments

Comment: Please create a separate question for this so that future users can look for solutions to one issue at a time. Also, explain your issue with some examples to make it more clear in the new post.. like what is the current behaviour based on the Mongo query and what is the expected behaviour. I hope that makes sense.

Comment: i have here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62105123/check-if-slice-reached-the-beginning-of-the-array