# MongoDB pagination on arrays - Check if $slice reached the beginning of the array

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

In my application i have an box where users can read comments. If some user scrolls down, it loads more and more comments, everything fine. I slice the array from the back to the begin because i use `$push` whenever somebody write some comment so i slice it like this `$slice: [ -5 , 5]`. This will slice the last 5 elements out of the array. The `-5` is actually an variable in my aggregation pipeline. Whenever i loaded some comments i decrease the value from `-5` to `-10` and so on so on. The problem i got here is if my array has an legth for example of 50, and i execute this slice `$slice: [ -70, 5]` i get the first 5 comments, but i expected to receive 0. The result is that i have an infinity scrollbar witch loads over and over the same 5 first comments. How do i fix this?

```
let result = await Post.aggregate([
    {
      $match: {
        _id: userId,
        "posts._id": postId
      }
    },
    {
      $addFields: {
        posts: {
          $map: {
            input: "$posts",
            as: "p",
            in: {
              _id: "$$p._id",
              comments: { $slice: ["$$p.comments", -start, 5] }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    },
    {
      $project: {
        posts: {
          $filter: {
            input: "$posts",
            as: "posts",
            cond: { $eq: ["$$posts._id", postId] }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  ]);
```

Comment: Just an observation; If you use array index to get elements, if  new item arrives while you are keeping count. Doesn't it all shift to the back and you would get duplicate items? Is it better to use a time based value, like `ObjectId` instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do is to use `$cond` operator :

**Query :**

```
let inputPosition = -70
let positionConverted = -position // 70
let maxNumber = 1000

db.collection.aggregate([
    {
      $project: {
        comments: {
          $slice: [ "$comments",
            { $cond: [ { $gte: [ { $size: "$comments" }, positionConverted ] }, inputPosition, maxNumber ] }, 5 ] }
      }
    }
  ])
```

**Test :** [mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/lq4QI2dj4Zd)

**Explanation :**

So syntax of `$slice` is `{ $slice: [ <array>, <position>, <n> ] }` from that if you pass a value larger than size of array for `<position>` then you'll get an empty array in response.

Here we're using `$cond` to conditionally send either value of `inputPosition` or value of `maxNumber` to `<position>`. Additionally, I've a hard coded value of `maxNumber` to `1000` but in general it all depends on your choice - You can use a lesser number, it doesn't matter, that number should be a greater value than size of your array, You can also you `size of array + 1` but instead of doing that operation if you believe your array is always less than 1000 then directly use `1000`.

**Ref :** [$slice](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/slice/index.html)

Comment: works great. But just 1 thing you need change `$gt` to `$gte`

Comment: there is a case where i have 21 elements, so when my input is 25 it wont execute the query, that means the 1 element wont be displayed

Comment: @Ifaruki : How big can be your array ? How about trying to reverse the array and then do pagination ? Each time reversing can be an overkill but how about that ? ***Or*** Maybe once you can update all docs by reversing the existing array & there after on new writes push new comments to `0` position of `comments` array using `$position` operator.

Comment: its 0 now, i dont know how big its in the future. i have done an query where i reverse the array and paginate through. this time i tried to slice it like this but seems to be harder then i thought

Comment: is it also possible to optimize this query, for me it looks kinda too big for slicing 5 items in an nested array

Comment: @Ifaruki : didn't find time, but definitely would update this answer if I get better answer..

Answer (score 1):

@lfaruki, I think you are on the right track reversing the array, as from the [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/slice/index.html), as also explained by @whoami

> `<position>` If positive, `$slice` determines the starting position from the start of the array. If `<position>` is greater than the number of elements, the `$slice` returns an empty array.

```
comments: {
  $reverseArray: { // reverse back
    $slice: [
      {
        $reverseArray: "$comments"
      },
      endOffset, // this starts from 0, 5, 10, 15, ...
      5
    ]
  }
}
```

I'm not sure what issues you faced when you try to implement it using the reverse array. But my general advice is it would have negative effect on performance on large arrays. If you already have your comments in a separate collection, better query it separately using **"time-based"** or **"cursor-based"** pagination. Because ultimately MongoDB has limits on document size and you don't want to process large arrays in aggregation.